# Nothing listening on port 80 and unable to connect to port 22 OS X - No firewall enabled on machine

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, port

I have just joined a new work place and cannot access port 22, this got me to trying to work out why when I try to access `ssh` it just hangs. Ultimately I want to connect to port 22 and ssh.

So I did a search for port 22 and this was reported

```
➜  render-service git:(master) ✗ sudo lsof -i ':22'
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd   1 root    8u  IPv4 0x2d460587397f64b      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   10u  IPv6 0x2d4605873976903      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   11u  IPv6 0x2d4605873976903      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   12u  IPv4 0x2d460587397f64b      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

Which got me to checking port 80 and it returns blank:

```
➜  render-service git:(master) ✗ sudo lsof -i ':80'
```

I assume the network here as a rather restricted area and I'll never be able to access port 22

[image]

The firewall is off also

[image]

Comment: There could be other firewalls than the one running locally on your computer's network stack. Where are you attempting to connect from? Many places have a policy for these things which should be your first priority -- if they are saying you cannot then don't push it even if you are able to figure out technical workarounds.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but not having access to port 22 is hugely frustrating.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest that you [edit] your question to provide the details I requested, rather than vent your frustration where nobody is able to do anything about it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your questions. I am connecting from my machine, via terminal which is connected via ethernet to the main network here at work.